# Where does the Wakanda Enterprise Server license file go, on a Mac OS Sierra system?

Tags: wakanda

Where should the Wakanda Enterprise Server license file be located in a Mac OS Sierra system? I signed up for the 30-day trial, and the instructions said `/Document/Wakanda/License`, but when I created that path and started the server, it said

> "License not found. Server running in Community mode"

I also tried `~/Documents/Wakanda/ and ~/Documents/Wakanda/License/` to no effect.  I can’t seem to find it in the documentation either, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

For Mac user, you need to add your license file here :

`/Users/<user>/Documents/Wakanda/license/license.key`
or 
`~/Documents/Wakanda/license/license.key`

There is not uppercase to `license`.

Comment: /Users/Documents/Wakanda/license/license.key does not work either.... any other suggestions?

Comment: I also tried adding a folder named / so the path was "/Users//Documents/Wakanda/license/license.key" as you suggested, but that didn't work either.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

/Users//Documents/Wakanda/license/license.key is the correct path, note that the license file downloaded is not called "license.key" you must rename it, and use lowercase "license" for both the folder name and the file name.  Thanks to Yann for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

/Document/Wakanda/License is the correct path, you have to create only the file "License" and put on it the license.key file and restart Wakanda Studio and Server.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused.  The "Document" folder did not exist at the root level of the boot drive, so I created it, created a folder in it called "Wakanda", and in that folder I put the license file I downloaded "license_5_.key".  It didn't work.  I renamed the file to "license.key", it still didn't work.  I renamed the file "license" no file extension.  Still doesn't work.  Where have I gone wrong?